# python csv.reader method fails when called within the object used in its argument

Tags: python, csv

I am using csv.reader(), but it fails when I use it from a method within a class if the argument to reader() is that object itself (i.e., "self).  The failure is non-intuitive.  When I call csv.reader() from outside the object, all is well.  Can somebody explain what conceptual error I've made?  Hope my explanation makes some sense: it probably is easier to read/invoke the code.

You can see that in **main** I first invoke the readDirList() method directly, and everything is happy.  However, if I invoke the readDirList() method of the dirList class (which is supposed to do the same thing), I get the odd "no next() method" error.  Befuddled, I am.

Thanks for taking a look!

(am using python 2.7.6 in Linux Mint 17.3)  Also BTW I get the same area if in **main** I omit the "mdl" stuff and jump right to the "mdl2" stuff.
    #!/usr/bin/python
    # example: why csv.reader.next() doe not work

```
import csv

class dirList(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.inFile = None
        return
    # a dirList object is iterable so that csv.reader can be used
    def __iter__(self):
        return self
    def next(self):
        line = self.inFile.next()
        return line
    def readDirList(self, sourceFile):
        # read csv file
        self.infile = open(sourceFile)
        print type(self) #yup, self is indeed of the right class which DOES have next() method
        rdr = csv.reader(self)
        for csvline in rdr:
            print csvline
        self.infile.close()
        return True
#----------------------------------------------------------------------
if __name__ == "__main__":
    # this works as expected
    mdl = dirList()
    mdl.inFile = open('tin.csv', 'r')
    rdr = csv.reader(mdl)
    for aaa in rdr:
        print aaa
    mdl.inFile.close()
    # when doing the same thing within a method of the object, it fails with:
    # AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'next'
    mdl2 = dirList()
    mdl2.readDirList('tin.csv')
    sys.exit()
#---- contents of file 'tin.csv' is as follows
"""
a,b,c
d,e,f
1,3,4
"""
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your file is in the variable `self.infile`, however, you are calling next on `self.inFile`, which is `None`. Simple typo.

Comment: Thank you!  Second pair of eyes, works every time.  Code is working now.